# Jquery cannot access $(this) in callback function

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, element

I am creating a plugin and it cannot access $(this). A simple overview of my plugin is

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin= function(options, callback) {
        return this.each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(){
                      // some plugin works ..

                      callback();
                });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then i attached my plugin to  a element like

```
$('p').myPlugin({
      // Some options
}, function(){
      alert('first test');
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

Here when the element p is clicked, i get the first alert, but i didn't get the 2nd alert.

The callback function is called, but unable to access `this`. 
Is there any problem with the defining or with code ? any alternative suggestion will also be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `callback();`, use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) to give it the right context (otherwise it's `window`), like this:

```
callback.apply(this);
```

[You can see the updated/working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/emue3/).

---

For a more complete overview here, you can pass more arguments if you want to that `callback`, for example if you wanted to make the `options` available, you could do this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin= function(options, callback) {
    return this.each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        callback.apply(this, [options]);
     });
   });
 };
})(jQuery);
```

Then call it like this:

```
$('p').myPlugin({
    thing: "thing1"
}, function(opts){
    alert(opts.thing); //thing1
});​
```

[You can give that one a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/emue3/1/), just add whatever arguments you want to that array, `callback()` will be called with those arguments :)

Answer (score 1):

Nick Craver is right. But for understanding what is going on follow this link:
http://howtonode.org/what-is-this

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post a complete example that uses the autocomplete widget?

Here is what I wanted to do...

```
    $('.suggest').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        typ = $(this).getAttr("class").split(" ")[2]
        ....
```

...but ***this*** returns undefined.  For now I am using ***document.activeElement***, but I would prefer Nick Craver's method.