# jQuery create interval within each cant access $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have three different image-slides on my website. The number of images inside the slide is generated from wordpress.

I need to check if a slide contains more elements than one, if yes then a slideshow has to start. Now i've got a problem i created the interval inside the jQuery each function and inside the interval i can't access the $(this) from the each. So nothing is happening when the interval is called.

```
$( ".home .images .image-slide div" ).each(function() {
    var count = $(this).children().length; 
    if (count > 1) {
        $(this).find("img:first-child").addClass("active");
        setInterval(function(){ 
            if($(this).find('.active').is(":last-child")){
                $(this).find('.active').removeClass("active").fadeOut().parent().find("img:first-child").addClass("active").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $(this).find('img.active').removeClass("active").fadeOut().next().fadeIn().addClass("active");
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

How can i access the inside the interval with $(this)?

Comment: You are going to need to read up on javascript closures. There are a lot of questions about this topic on SO and it is a very fundamental property of javascript. Beyond that, some advice that would have avoided this problem, Any time you repeat code a bunch you should abstract it. You use `$(this)` a bunch. You should assign that to a variable as soon as you use it and only use the variable. This saves the efffort of the computer having to recreate the object every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery cannot access $(this) in callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329021/jquery-cannot-access-this-in-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marie pointed in the comments, you need to work around the closure.

Here is a simple way to make it work, by moving the `$(this)` outside of the `setInterval`.

```
$( ".home .images .image-slide div" ).each(function() {
    var count = $(this).children().length; 
    if (count > 1) {
        $(this).find("img:first-child").addClass("active");
        var self = $(this);
        setInterval(function(){ 
            if(self.find('.active').is(":last-child")){
                self.find('.active').removeClass("active").fadeOut().parent().find("img:first-child").addClass("active").fadeIn();
            } else {
                self.find('img.active').removeClass("active").fadeOut().next().fadeIn().addClass("active");
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```